# Variable and constant

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use the following code but I don't have constant ( 2 and 4 in this example ) I need to use variable.

Here's the code :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

var range = source.getRange("B2:D4");

// This copies the data in B2:D4 in the source sheet to
// D4:F6 in the second sheet
range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 4, 6, 4, 6);
```

source : [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange%28Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var col1 = 2;
var col2 = 4;

var range = source.getRange("B" + col1 + ":D" + col2);
```

Comment: Or look at the other getRange methods that receive the row/column index.